# Get formula result from Excel cell using Spire.xls

Tags: c#, excel, spire.xls

I'm trying to read data in a xlsx file (in C# WPF with spire xls) but when the cell contains a formula I can only get the formula and I don't know how to get the result

I've tried this :

```
    wb.LoadFromFile("...");
    wb.CalculateAllValue();
    colsheet = wb.Worksheets[6];
    SwitchName = colsheet.Range["B1"].Value;
```

and with that I get : `"=IF(OR(I215=0,J215=0),"",I215+J215-1)"` but I want the result and not the formula. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Object ob = colsheet.Range["B1"].FormulaValue;` instead of this line `SwitchName = colsheet.Range["B1"].Value;`